# When creating a subclass one variable from the super class isn't created (JAVA)

Tags: java, eclipse, class, inheritance, arraylist

i currently struggling with a strange problem..
i'm creating an instance from a subclass called `StandardTruck` which inherits from a super class `Truck`.
all the variables from the `Truck` class and the `StandardTruck` subclass are initialized and created except one - truckID

The variable `truckID` should be increasing integer number after every Truck instance construction so i figured it should be static variable

```
public abstract class Truck {

    static private int truckID = 2000;
    private String licensePlate;
    private String truckModel;
    private boolean available= true;
    private int timeLeft;
    private ArrayList<Package> packages = new ArrayList<Package>();
    
    
    //Constructors
    public Truck() {
        this.licensePlate = randomNumber(100,999) + "-" + randomNumber(10,99) + "-" + randomNumber(100,999);
        this.truckModel= "M"+ randomNumber(0,4);
        truckID++;
    }
    
    public Truck(String licensePlate, String truckModel) {
        this.licensePlate=licensePlate;
        this.truckModel=truckModel;
        truckID++;
    }
```

```
public class StandardTruck extends Truck{
    
    private int maxWeight;
    private Branch destination;
    
    
    //Constructors
    public StandardTruck() {
        super();
        maxWeight = randomNumber(200, 400);
        System.out.println("Creating "+ this.toString());
        
    }
    '''
    public StandardTruck(String licensePlate,String truckModel,int maxWeight) {
        super(licensePlate, truckModel);
        this.maxWeight= maxWeight;
        System.out.println("Creating "+ this.toString());
    }
```

So after creating a StandardTruck instance or any other instance that inherits from Truck , the variable `truckID` isn't initialized or created
and because of that , any time i'm trying to do something with any of the trucks i created , i'm always getting the last truckID created..

am i missing something??

[image: i'm getting access to a list of trucks and accessing to a truck by index]

Comment: `truckID` is static, so it belongs to the class, rather than individual instances. Is that a typo?

Comment: @Sweeper not it isn't a typo , so if it's static and belongs to the class , how i can initialize that variable to a first value and then increase it by one every time i use the constructor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`truckID` *is* initialised, but since it is static, it belongs to the class, rather than individual instances, so it doesn't show up on the debugger.

It seems like you need another non-static field `truckID`. But fields can't have duplicate names, so I suggest you rename the static one to `nextTruckID`:

```
static private int nextTruckID = 2000;
private int truckID;
```

The constructors can then be written like this:

```
public Truck() {
    this.licensePlate = randomNumber(100,999) + "-" + randomNumber(10,99) + "-" + randomNumber(100,999);
    this.truckModel= "M"+ randomNumber(0,4);
    truckID = nextTruckID++;
}

public Truck(String licensePlate, String truckModel) {
    this.licensePlate=licensePlate;
    this.truckModel=truckModel;
    truckID = nextTruckID++;
}
```

Comment: didn't know about  that static variables isn't passing in inheritence , thanks man!!

Answer (score 0):

Your truckID isn't inherited to your subclass, because its static. In order to get a increasing truckID you would have to specify a object variable

```
private int truckId;
```

and a class variable

```
private static int truckIdCounter = 2000; // 2000 is the start value
```

in your Truck class. In the constructor of your Truck class you then can set the truckId for your Truck instance and increase the static truck id:

```
this.truckId = truckIdCounter;
truckIdCounter++;
```

Now you should be able to access truckId in your subclass instance.

Answer (score 0):

Static variables are shared across a single class which means any instance you created will have the same shared truckId. You should be creating a single static lastTruckId and a private instance variable which is truckId, that way you can assign the latest truckId and increment lastTruckId.
And you can't inherit private variables, so you can either make a new getter, make it public, or just protected depending on your situation in the abstract class.

Try this:

```
abstract class Truck {
  private static int lastTruckId = 2000;

  public Truck() {
    lastTruckId++;
  }

  public static int getLastTruckId() {
    return lastTruckId;
  }
}

class StandardTruck extends Truck {
  private int truckId;

  public StandardTruck() {
    super();
    this.truckId = getLastTruckId();
  }

  public int getTruckId() {
    return truckId;
  }
}
```